# Use Pygame in Kivy to be packaged to an Android app, is this Ok?

Tags: android, python-3.x, pygame, kivy

In a perspective:

The user interface features in `kivy` is easier to handle, compared to `pygame`. But, in `pygame`, it is convenient to manipulate graphics with `blit` : do `blit`, then clear all graphics on the surface after finishing an event, then `blit` again, etc.

It is also more flexible (based on my limited exp. on this), because the pygame activity can be controlled using `while` and can get info of the events with one line of code.

Is it possible to package a `kivy` app, that uses `pygame` module, for Android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is also more flexible (based on my limited exp. on this), because the pygame activity can be controlled using while and can get info of the events with one line of code.

It isn't more flexible, just a different API. Kivy's drawing API is much more modern and closer to how drawing with opengl actually works.

> Is it possible to package a kivy app, that uses pygame module, for Android?

Kivy used to use a modified pygame backend on Android, which is still available using `--bootstrap=pygame` when using python-for-android. I think at least some pygame commands worked when this was used, including drawing commands. However, use of the pygame api was never really supported, and the pygame bootstrap is nowadays deprecated in favour of SDL2 - we won't deliberately break it, but it has issues that will probably never be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Flexible in an angle of : `kivy` already provide many widget classes or framework, and have to adapt to it, while in `pygame` we may build from scratch (creative algorithms and logic) so we may move more flexible. But I am starting to get used to it, the `blit` and clear screen in pygame may correspond to `add_widget` and `remove_widget`. So if I import some other modules such as `math`, `numpy`, `time`, will it be able to work on android? I am working on Windows.